# Convergence in Probability for a sequence

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Given sample space $\Omega=[0,1]$ and P( ) the uniform probability measure
define random variable
$X_1,X_2,.....$ by

$X_{2n}=\begin{cases}
e^{2n} & \text{if $\omega\ \epsilon\ [0,\frac{1}{2n}]$} \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

$X_{2n+1} =
\begin{cases}
e^{2n} & \text{if $\omega\ \epsilon\ [1-\frac{1}{2n},1]$} \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}\\$

n=0,1,2,...

show that $(X)_{n\geq1}$ converges in probability to zero

I'm not allowed to use the fact that it converges to zero almost surely

I think I can show that both the sequences above converge in probability to zero but is that sufficient to show $(X)_{n\geq1}$ converges in probability to zero.

I cant seem to find any examples in textbooks where the sequence has been split up into two sequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily compute $P(X_{2n} \neq 0)$ and $P(X_{2n+1} \neq 0)$. Hint: What is $X_{2n}^{-1}(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\})$ and $X_{2n+1}^{-1}(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\})$?

If you have done that, it should be easy to see that $$
  \lim_{n\to\infty} P(X_{n} \neq 0) = 0
$$

---

You don't really need this here - the two sequences of probabilities are very "compatible" - but it holds generally that if $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{2n+1} = a$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_{2n} = a$ then also $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = a$. You can show that with a run-off-the-mill $\epsilon-\delta$-criterium. You pick an $\epsilon$, find two deltas $\delta_1,\delta_2$- one for each series, and then pick the larger one.